# CSS Flexbox Align Center

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm trying to align content in a flex box centered (vertical and horizontal). In my example it works as long the screen is big enough.

Problems:

1. When the content is bigger than 100vh in the ".wrapper" class. The content will be cut of at the top.
2. When i set the ".wrapper" to "100vh" and I add the ".header" div, this div should be excluded from the "100vh" otherwise i will get a scrollbar for nothing.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>FlexBox</title>
        <meta name="infoription" content="">

        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            body {
                background-color: #f8f9fa;
                font-family: Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
                color: #55595c;
            }

            .wrapper {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-content: center;
                height: 100vh;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }

            .content {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                max-height: 350px;
                max-width: 300px;
                min-height: 350px;
                min-width: 300px;
                margin: 10px;
                position: relative;
                border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
                border-radius: 0.25rem;
            }     

            .content:after {    
                /* background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; */
                bottom: 0;
                content: "";
                display: block;
                height: 10px;
                left: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                background: #55595c;
                transition: width 0.4s ease 0s, left 0.4s ease 0s;
                width: 0;
            }

            .content:hover:after { 
                width: 100%; 
                left: 0;
            }

            .thumb {
                background-color: #55595c;
                height: 150px;
                border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
                border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
                color: #ffffff;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .info {
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: justify;
            }

            /* Responsive layout - screen is bigger than 1000px wide */
            @media (min-width: 1000px) {
                .bodysize {
                    width: 1000px;
                    margin: auto;
                }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bodysize">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Example Page</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <h3>Thumbnail</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>[1]</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean turpis felis, dapibus ac tellus at, imperdiet consectetur ante. Mauris vulputate arcu nibh, et convallis felis mattis id.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <h3>Thumbnail</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>[2]</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean turpis felis, dapibus ac tellus at, imperdiet consectetur ante. Mauris vulputate arcu nibh, et convallis felis mattis id.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
           
            <div class="content">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <h3>Thumbnail</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>[3]</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean turpis felis, dapibus ac tellus at, imperdiet consectetur ante. Mauris vulputate arcu nibh, et convallis felis mattis id.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="content">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <h3>Thumbnail</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>[4]</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean turpis felis, dapibus ac tellus at, imperdiet consectetur ante. Mauris vulputate arcu nibh, et convallis felis mattis id.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="content">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <h3>Thumbnail</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>[5]</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean turpis felis, dapibus ac tellus at, imperdiet consectetur ante. Mauris vulputate arcu nibh, et convallis felis mattis id.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="content">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <h3>Thumbnail</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>[6]</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean turpis felis, dapibus ac tellus at, imperdiet consectetur ante. Mauris vulputate arcu nibh, et convallis felis mattis id.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="content">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <h3>Thumbnail</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>[7]</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean turpis felis, dapibus ac tellus at, imperdiet consectetur ante. Mauris vulputate arcu nibh, et convallis felis mattis id.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="content">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <h3>Thumbnail</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>[8]</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean turpis felis, dapibus ac tellus at, imperdiet consectetur ante. Mauris vulputate arcu nibh, et convallis felis mattis id.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="content">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <h3>Thumbnail</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>[9]</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean turpis felis, dapibus ac tellus at, imperdiet consectetur ante. Mauris vulputate arcu nibh, et convallis felis mattis id.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

**Example pictures:**

[Problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu1yk.png) - scrollbar because of "height: 100vh;".

[Problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfc4P.png) - content floating out of the browser top. also because of "height: 100vh;".

**Questions:**

1) How can I set a dynamic height so the wrapper always fills the rest of the available space?
2) If the content is smaller than than the wrapper height it should be centered vertical but if the content is bigger, there is not center needed.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

**>>> SOLUTION <<<**

I added the .bodysize, removed the height from the wrapper and added "flex-grow: 1" to the wrapper. .bodysize { display: flex; flex-flow: column; height: 100vh; }

Comment: you should consider using media queries.  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: `height: 100vh;` should be moved to`.bodysize`, if you want all your content to be visible without scrollbar, you should consider resizing the font size, and all paddings and margins you might have

Comment: @ZohirSalak: when I move the 100vh to .bodysize than the content is not longer centered vertically. Same as when I try the idea of "Juliana García".

Comment: @ThetAung: this was also my idea. i',m using already one media query. is there a possibility to make a media query which says "if the body is bigger as 100vh than...". is this possible?

Comment: Yes You need to center them using flex or some other method `.bodysize { height: 100vh;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-content: center;flex-direction:column;}`

Comment: @ZohirSalak: i added two example pics. maybe i do something wrong but moving/adding your suggestions to .bodysize is not changing anything for me.

Comment: What i suggested is for centering the content, nothing is changing because there's no left over space for the content to be centered within, Also like i said before *if you want all your content to be visible without scrollbar, you should consider resizing the font size, and all paddings and margins you might have*

Comment: okay i found the solution. I added the .bodysize, removed the height from the wrapper and added "flex-grow: 1" to the wrapper.

            .bodysize {
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: column;
                height: 100vh;
            }

now all is as i wanted. i simple didn't understand the flex grow/shrink at the beginning.

Comment: @x0100 Of course, it's possible. That's what media queries are  for. Check out this tutorials to learn more -  https://w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp   - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: @x0100 I'll just tell you the solution. We use max-width `@media only screen and (max-width: 100vh) {
       .classname {
       . . .
}
      }` But please, learn more about it in details from the links I provided

Answer (score 0):

Try to set height: auto; and max-height: 100vh; at your wrapper.

Otherwise, your wrapper always would have 100% height even having few elements inside. The scrollbar would should appear when the content exceeds 100vh.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100vh;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: When the content is bigger than the screen height (100vh), than it works and the content is not floating out of the top screen (it is not cut off). But when the content is smaller than the screen height it is not centered vertically (because the height is set to "auto".